# How do i show line charts (spline) with bubbles

Tags: highcharts

I'd like to show something like below, i see that bubble chart supports only number/literals on XAxis but I want to plot x axis as time, Y as Number value and Z (bubble) as number.

[image]

Is it possible

Comment: you can use marker for each point check http://jsfiddle.net/c5brw8ze/1/

Comment: Thanks that would work